# Having Issues with in_category , need help

Tags: posts

I used this code to display content from my custom fields only where post category id is 5, but all data from the custom fields show above the table in a straight line like a paragraph.

```
<?php
$post = $wp_query->post; if ( in_category('5') ) {
echo "<table><tr><td> ".the_field('song_title')."</td></td>
        <tr><td>
        <b>Artist: </b> ".the_field('artist')."</td></tr>
        <tr><td>
        <b >Song Title:</b> ".the_field('song_title')."</td></tr>
        <tr><td>
        <b>Song Lenght:</b> ".the_field('song_lenght')."</td></tr></table>
        ";
}  ?>
```

Comment: First `<tr>` is not closed in the first line, you close `td` tag twice instead of `tr`

Comment: Welcome to WordPress Stack Exchange! We love to help. But code reviews are considered off-topic as they simply are too localized, whereas this Q+A site seeks to provide canonical answers that also help future readers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to this community Prezido. `the_field()` function has echo in it. There is no problem with `in_category()` function. You need to use `get_field()` function when you echo the values of fields.

I've updated your code. This version should work as expected.

```php
<?php
    $post = $wp_query->post;
if ( in_category( '5' ) ) {
     echo '<table>
     <tr><td> ' . get_field( 'song_title' ) . '</td></tr>
    <tr><td><b>Artist: </b> ' . get_field( 'artist' ) . '</td></tr>
    <tr><td><b >Song Title:</b> ' . get_field( 'song_title' ) . '</td></tr>
    <tr><td><b>Song Lenght:</b> ' . get_field( 'song_lenght' ) . '</td></tr>
    </table>
    ';  }
```

Comment: Thanks man, I already used a seperate single.php file to achieve that.
I really appreciate your time.

Is there a link to a tutorial where i can learn how to create a plugin that will add custom fields to my post. not like a plugin but a code in my theme file?

I have been trying to create a custom field that ads itself automatically to my post whenever i choose a specific category. Note, I do not need a plugin for this

Comment: You can add an implement of javascript which can add custom fields (with hidden inputs etc)  to the post when you select the certain category from WordPress category box. I don't know is there any tutorial about this, but it can be done with some research.